# What is wrong with this recursive Promise function with jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, promise, lazy-evaluation

I am working on my scripts for ReST API processes. Now I need a function which keeps retrying to request to the API as many as possible in few seconds.

So I wrote some Promise abstractions and I made something like below:

```
$(function () {
  var $el = $('#test');
  function api (message) {
    return $.ajax('/echo/json/', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: { json: JSON.stringify({ message: message }), delay: 2000 },
      timeout: 1000
    });
  }
  // Process to keep retrying an API request as many as possible in 3 seconds
  retried(_.bind(api, undefined, 'Hello, world.'), 3000)
  .then(function (dat) {
    $el.text(dat.message);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) $el.css('color', 'red');
    $el.text(err.message);
  });
});
```

Some functions I made for the above are below:

```
// Promise wrapper
var promisify = function (func) {
  var funcPartial = function () {
    var funcArgs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var dfr = new $.Deferred(), promiseArgs = [ dfr.resolve, dfr.reject ];
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      func.apply(undefined, _.union(promiseArgs, funcArgs));
    }, 1);
    return dfr.promise();
  };
  return funcPartial;
};

// Promise abstraction for recursive call
retried = promisify(function (resolve, reject, done, duration, start) {
  if (!_.isNumber(start)) start = +(new Date());
  return done()
  .then(resolve, function (err) {
    var stop = +(new Date());
    if (duration <= stop - start) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      return retried(done, duration, start);
    }
  });
});
```

The process finishes in a correct condition, but the `retried` function won't return Promise chain.

I am really stacked. Can someone point me out the wrong points to correct the implementation above?

Here's the entire demo script.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/japboy/bz0m9gbo/2/)**

Thank you.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum below, I have just noticed that I did not need `promisify` to make `retried` function at all. This was completely shame question, but thanks again to all the people replied on this question.

This is revised `retried` function which does not need `promisify` at all...

```
var retried = function (done, duration, start) {
  if (!_.isNumber(start)) start = +(new Date());
  return done()
  .then(function (dat) {
    return dat;
  }, function (err) {
    var stop = +(new Date());
    if (duration > stop - start) return retried(done, duration, start);
    return err;
  });
};
```

I updated the demo and it works fine now XD

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/japboy/bz0m9gbo/) (revised)**

Comment: `retried` returns the funcPartial function ... should it `return funcPartial()` instead?

Comment: Well, the first thing that's wrong with it is that it's ridiculously complicated to just retry - so much more complicated than needed that it's quite hard to follow your code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think `promisify` should return the function `funcPartial` instead of the result of `funcPartial` because `promisify` is supposed to be an higher-order function to create a Promise function.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right. But I already have many Promise based API wrapper functions which are supposed to be retri-able. So just wondering if I could make an abstraction to wrap them with Promise interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for retrying is very complicated. You're "promisifying" a function with resolve and reject and performing [explicit construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). How would you implement retry in synchronous code?

```
do {
   var failed = false;
   try { 
       var val = fn();
   } catch(e){
       failed = true;
   }
} while(failed);
```

But we can't really do that, because we can't use loops, we can however use recursion instead:

```
function retry(fn){
    try {
       return fn(); // call the function
    } catch(e){
       return retry(fn); // retry it again
    }
}
```

Now, adding promises in just means that failure isn't through try/catch but through the promise's resolution/lack of:

```
function retry(fn) {
    return fn().then(null, function(e){ 
        return retry(fn); // on failure handler, retry again.
    });
}
```

This implementation has the benefit of not depending on the promise library used (it'll use the same type `fn` returns).

As a side note, please don't ignore errors. Even network errors - at least log them somewhere :)

Comment: If they're going to ignore your good advice and not handler the error altogether then you could simplify: `return fn().then(null, retry.bind(null, fn));`

Comment: I mostly wanted to emphasize what's being done, I'd probably just do `fn().catch(e => retry(fn))` but that has even more constraints. I guess it's about finding the balance.

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't see any ES6 code in the question so didn't want to jump the gun on that one.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum After I read your advice, I've just noticed that I did unnecessary Promise wrapping like your said "explicit construction." Oops. So I didn't need the `promisify` function to make `retried` function because I passed Promise as the first argument for `retried`... Shame. Thank you for your kind and careful advice XD